# youtube api movie rental / purchase

Tags: api, youtube, movie

I am wondering if it is possible with the youtube api to get a list of purchasable, or rentable movies. When I go to the youtube website and I am logged into my google account I can see movies to purchase and their prices.

I would like to offer this option in my application ( http://www.tastefilter.com ). We would like to offer links to youtube so people can watch movies directly from their tablets. However I can't find anything in the youtube v2 or v3 documentation on purchasability of a movie, on how to filter a search query to only return those movies, and finally, no pricing info.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the YouTube v2.0 Data API. There is a search parameter called `paid_content` that lets you retrieve information about rentable movies only.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=en#paid-contentsp